# When I render a content my pages jumping in React.js?

Tags: css, reactjs

I try to develop a movie app with React.js. I make a requests to MovieDB, and after that I render a an image and title for each movie. But for some reason when the content is loaded the whole page jump. When I remove the content from the API everything is fine. I try to use min-height: 'some value bigger than a content' and that works, but it doesn't work for responsive design.

This is a movie card

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./MovieCard.module.css";
const MovieCard = (props) => {
  const { title, backdrop_path, id } = props.movie;
  return (
    <div className={styles.card}>
      <div className={styles["image-container"]}>
        <Link to={`/movie/${id}`}>
          <img
            className={ styles.image }
            src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${backdrop_path} `}
            alt="movie-poster"
          />
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <h3 className={styles["card-title"]}>{title}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MovieCard;
```

This is a movie card CSS

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card:hover .card-title {
    color: #B5CF4D;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    box-shadow: 0 -10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-title {
    width: 80%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome! Please add some code.

Comment: What do you mean by "jump", exactly?

Comment: If you like I can send a url to GitHub

Comment: The page make simple move  on X axis.

Comment: Can you add some minimal demo ?